# use external editor in Octave on OSX

Tags: macos, octave

I want to use Sublime Text as my default editor for Octave, but cant get it to work. 
The location of my Sublime Text app is in the /Applications/ folder as usually.

For example putting `EDITOR (“/Applications/SublimeText.app”)` results in the following error:

```
parse error near line 1 of file /Users/czapla/.octaverc

   syntax error

>>> EDITOR (“/Applications/SublimeText.app”)
            ^
error: source: error sourcing file '/Users/czapla/.octaverc'`
```

FYI: Yes `SublimeText`, this is name of the application, no spaces in between, I changed it to avoid having to escape spaces - I wasnt sure how that would be handled by Octave.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You know the difference between `“”` and `""`?

Comment: No, please do explain.

Comment: Well, the former ones are designed to look fancy, and the latter ones are to be used in programming.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what different things you tried to place in your `.octaverc` file. The following should work `EDITOR ("path_to_your_sublime_aplication")`. It doesn't need to be the full path, whatever works to call it from the command line should suffice. For example, `EDITOR ("gedit")` works fine on my system.

Also, it is important to set this before calling any function that makes use of it. The variable is persistent during an Octave session after being accessed the first time (and defaults to emacs).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sublime Text 3 on OS X

Octave programs are running perfectly. So you can try the below mentioned steps

Open Sublime

Goto `Tools` --> `Build System` --> `New Build System...`

Paste this code

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/octave-3.8.0", "$file"],
"selector": "source.m"
}
```

Save it as Octave.sublime-build

Now use Octave as your build system

Use `⌘` + `B` to run your code.

Enjoy!